# Why does my app "data" space increases so fast?

Tags: ios, swift, memory, storage

My takes has a fixed size of around 100Mo, which is normal.

However, I noticed the "Files and data" category was increasing EXTREMELY fast while the app has been opened two or three times. (Up to 300Mo, it even went to 4Go!).

Since I do have a lot of code and I do know how to spot what increases that much the size of the app, I won't post any code (except if requested) but could you please tell me what kind of actions usually creates that kind of problem and with which instrument I can spot the problem?

I would be glad to know someone can help me out.

Comment: [Download the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121613/browse-the-files-created-on-a-device-by-the-ios-application-im-developing-on-w/28161494) of your app and track what are the files taking space.

Comment: @Soroush thank you for your answer I downloaded it but it seems there are no files taking that much space, and anyway, just to remind you, the memory/space is increasing over time?

Comment: @Soroush I may have answered too fast. I found a "tmp" file with 3 "stack logs" taking up to 130Mo. Could you tell me more about it please?

Comment: can you tell what is the path to that file?

Comment: @Soroush AppData/tmp/stack-logs.2812.10213c000.Penfriends.ZHJ3vi.index Is that what you want?

Comment: follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196443/how-to-remove-tmp-directory-files-of-an-ios-app) to flush tmp folder every time your app starts. Check if the problem resolves.

Comment: @Soroush I tried this. I hope this will solve the problem. Thank you for your help so far.