# How to prevent upload method save image to /tmp folder with Alamofire (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

Currently, I have method for upload image to server and I have no idea why that image is saved to /tmp folder. ( that cause security issue because I have to upload some sensitive data like id card image. )

Can I prevent network for save image to temp folder or can I clear temp folder ?

Comment: You can clear temp data. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37043842/14733292

Comment: @RajaKishan Thanks Raja, If I clear /tmp during app running, Will it affect anything ?

Comment: No. Just clear temp data after image upload.