# Reduce base64 encoded string size

Tags: ios, swift, base64, png

I am using the following method to save the PNG image to `UserDefaults`:

```
func convertImageToBase64String (img: UIImage) -> String {
    return img.pngData()?.base64EncodedString() ?? ""
}
```

The issues are that this data is using significantly Documents & Data storage:
[image]

And for some reason even if this data is removed from `UserDefaults`, this amount do not change.

I would like to fix this issues, but need to use PNG images as transparent background is important.

Comment: Storing images in userDefaults is not recommended.

Comment: @RameshSanghar how should I store them locally?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648518/save-images-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: No need to use PNG. You can use HEIC which supports transparency as well and it is much lighter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I found out PNG files were not using significant storage. The issue was that original images were being stored in temporary data. I managed to fix this issue following this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37043842/14880207

I followed Ramesh Sanghar suggestion as well and stored images in the way he suggested.